# Mixed-strategy Nash equilibria

Tags: game-theory

Is the following statement always true:

> if there is a mixed-strategy Nash equilibria then it is unique.

I know that there can be several pure strategy Nash equilibrias.

Answer (score 4):

> **Shameless Advertisement:** [Game Theory proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47845/game-theory?referrer=MGta8a5T8SlJlb1swuXPYQ2)
>   on Area 51 that you should totally follow!

**No**. The easiest way to prove this is by counterexample. Expanding [matching pennies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_pennies), we can create a game with two mixed strategies (players either mix between A and B or between C and D):

[image: Dual Matching Pennies]

What *might* be true about that statement is for a mix of particular pure strategies for two players, there is a unique mixed strategy equilibrium. This presumes that there is a threshold  after which you switch from using strategy $0$ to strategy $1$. At this threshold, your opponent is ambivalent between her strategies. As depicted below, the intersection (and hence mix) will be unique.

[image: Reaction Correspondence Matching Pennies]